# How to read the json response when a 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error occur in C# Visual Studio

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, rest, httpwebresponse

I'm sending some JSON data to a web service using "PUT" method, but I'm having *422 unprocessable entity* error. 
 How can I actually see the server response in JSON? I digged deep into the exception but i still can't find the json response.

Ex:

JSON Request:

```
{
  customer:
  {
    name: "asd",
    address: "test"
  }
}
```

and if everything was ok it should response to me some JSON data.

Ex:

```
{
  customer:
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "asd",
    address: "test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can catch WebExpection and get Response from that and extract the correct error message:

Code :

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       var data = sr.ReadToEnd();                    
       throw new ApplicationException(data);
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could manually test this rest service with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). 
422 HTTP error explanation: *The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors*.
So check for example if JSON data you're sending is in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: You cannot get a detailed answer in json specifying the syntax error than you have. It will be a manual trial and error process, to find the error.

As mentionned by user3470814, you should catch this kind of error and do something with it in your application.

And as mentionned by lucask, Fiddler will help you to see the exact string sent in your request.